# How is flurry able to detect when a user installs an ios app from a provided link?

Tags: ios, web-applications, flurry

Flurry can give you a URL that redirects to your app on the App Store, and they can tell you how many people install the app by using that URL. How do they do this?

Comment: Are they really measuring installs? It sounds more like they use it to estimate how many that viewed your app page on appstore.

Comment: @Karl-JohanSjögren It claims to be actual installs, and it does seem like that is what it is. Some days it shows me as 5 clicks with 2 installs, other days it shows as 20 clicks with 0 installs. One of the main selling points of it is that you can see which sources of traffic   result in higher install rates.  http://www.flurry.com/flurry-user-acquisition-analytics.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found the answer on Quora, answered by the CTO of Flurry. They use various data points to tie a certain click to a certain user of the app. They claim to be about 90% accurate.

Data points they use include time of click vs time of install, device type, location of user, etc.

http://www.quora.com/Flurry/How-does-Flurry-user-acquisition-work-1